# smallest cog of cassette rubbing on seatstay

Tags: chain, cassette, rear-wheel, sprocket, dropouts

I built up a NOS late 90s steel frame with a similar era Campagnolo Chorus 9 speed groupset. Has gone well, except the stays/dropouts don't seem to quite like a 9 speed cassette. The second smallest cog (14T) rubs a tiny bit and the smallest cog (13T) rubs a lot, so as to be unusable. I've set my limitscrew to keep me off the smallest cog and have done lots of km that way, but I'd really like to use the smallest cog and am trying to work out how. I tried swapping the hub spacers, but on this particular hub, that would have moved the dish way too far to the side. So basically I'm trying to figure out the cleanest hack (bonus if it's cheap as well) to get the full cassette usable on this frame.

I've attached a picture for clarity.

[image: some nice chain-seatstay rub]

Oh also, OLN of the hub (a fulcrum racing 7) is 130 and it fits without trouble, but given the age, it's possible it was originally a 126, though I think the paint job is original so perhaps not (I took off the paint around the dropouts, when I, er, discovered this problem).

Comment: I suspect you're simply asking the frame to do something it isn't designed to do.  But you might be able to fix it by inserting a spacer on the axle.  May need a slightly longer axle, though, and you'd need to re-dish the wheel.

Comment: If your cassette had a smaller smallest cog, would you use it? e.g. http://www.ribblecycles.co.uk/sp/road-track-bike/cassettes-cassettes-bbb-9-speed-cassette-campag/bbbacass098 has an 11 tooth option.

Comment: @armb yeah, though there are two points there (1) I'd like to keep my biggest the same size, and (2)I don't know if that would be enough. Is the diameter reduced enough to keep it clear? I tend to thing daniel-r-hicks spacer type solution is the only way to go. Actually the spacer was sorta my thought before posting, but wondering if it would work, or if there's a better idea...

Comment: @DanielRHicks do you think a 1mm washer would be enough? when (as mentioned in the Q) I swapped hub spacers it was either shift the dish about 10mm or nothing, and that would have basically put the rim over the non-drive side of the hub...

Comment: @DanielRHicks considering a slightly more committal/expensive solution, is this something that some hubs/wheelsets might be better at dealing with than others? If so, where might I be able to work out a good replacement?

Comment: I wonder if there might be some way to shift the cassette left on the shaft, without changing the axle relative to the hub proper?  From the photo it looks like there may be about 5mm of space available there (though one needs to be wary of getting the derailer into the spokes).

Comment: Is the hub/axel/skewer all assembled correctly?

Comment: Basically, all bets are off on this thing.  First, as Ken suggests, double-check that everything is assembled correctly.  Then look for any "easy" fix that will move the cassette inward a couple of mm.  Failing that you need to consider whether you want to go to the trouble and expense of trying additional spacers, given that it may not work out.

Comment: You could avoid redishing the wheel by putting a spacer on _both_ sides, but that would spread the frame a bit more. You could probably get away without a longer axle though - see http://sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#axleadjustment "Axle length".

Comment: If it's assembled correctly, I'd be very surprised if you could easily move the cassette closer to the wheel. (If it's not assembled properly, well there's your problem, but I think it would show up as more than the rubbing. Worth checking though, as Ken and Daniel say.)

Comment: If you do get the cassette further in, even by using a different hub, you might want to see if you can get away with a shorter bottom bracket axle too, to keep the chainline unchanged.

Comment: 11-12-13-... casette, plus a change to a smaller chainring in the front, if the gearing is to high, e.g. compact 48T.  By the way, in this problem it's actually the chain that is rubbing. I.e. the cassette doesn't rub by itself, but when the chain is on the second cog, it rubs a little, the way I understand it. In this situation, it's hard to see how the chain could even be seating properly on the smallest cog. If the chain is already touching the stay on the second cog, how can it have room to derail into its proper space on the smallest cog.

Comment: A 13T is quite big - I'd guess it should have an 11T small cog with a 12 and then a 13 or 14 beside it.

Answer (score 3):

Add a spacer and re-dish. Or move some spacers from the non drive side over the the drive side (if they exist) if you don't want to open up the frame (that will require opening up the hub likely). 1mm is not a big deal. You will also have to fiddle with the limits on your derailleur and adjust shifting accordingly.

Or get a different cogset with something smaller like 11. There are lots of options for cogsets... unless you are being really perticular about the groupo. I don't know Campy stuff that well but on Shimano the smallest cog is always seperate. You could simply swap that... the jumb might reduce shifting performance but you'll get more function than you currently have.

Last option (maybe should be first) is simply to move the wheel up or down if it has dropouts that accomodate that. You'd have to adjust brake pads if you did that but that would be the simplest.